# Why my changes are not displaying to the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

(this a long text but it's necessary for you to understand what I'm struggling with)

I've been trying to find a solution to this but I just couldn't find any info related to this so I wonder if it has to do something with my computer.

The problem is that when I am coding working on website in neither Sublime Text or VSC, (in the beginning everything was okay, I used to refresh the page or use a local server and my changes display on the Web page)  any changes I make in the .html, .css or .js files don't show on the browser.

I tried closing and re-opening the text editor and the files, (that used to work at first) but now that doesn't work anymore, any simple change made after this "forzing" happens, just doesn't display on the browser.  I tried also using opera, mozilla, chrome, and the problems persist.

I sent the files once to a friend of mine,  he opened the .html file and my changes were working. He resend me the code after he used it, I pasted it (the same I sent him before that wasn't working) and then  magically it worked!!!!

Now every time that happens I have to have Another personas computer to open the .html file, they resend it to me, I paste it again in order to make it work. This is so annoying and frustrating. If any of you could help me with anything to fix this, I'd very much appreciate it.

So in short,  until some point my changes are displayed, but after that, the page stays the same as when it "freezes" and no matter which file I modify, the page just doesn't show changes after that freezing point
Thanks for your atttention

Comment: Make sure you clear your browser's cache - or do a full page refresh to have your changes show up (in Windows it is `ctrl` + `shift` + `F5`) - Also make sure the page you are loading is the same page your are editing (sounds silly but it can happen)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try clearing the cache.

Comment: Reloading the page doesn't work either,  and yeah the file I am modifying is the same that freezes

Comment: ok, that's not normal... how are you 'serving' the files to the browser?

Comment: Try adding ?a=1 (or anything relly) to the end of the address when you are calling it in your browser to see if that forces a reload.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't work on a local computer, you can always use an online editor like [Replit](https://replit.com/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) (they worked quite well for me) ...

Comment: Oh I see, I'll try those and see if it fixes the issue.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the files aren't correctly saved into your working directory. If you go into your terminal and navigate to the directory these files you're working on are in and type ls it will show all the files in this directory. If your files aren't there then you know you didn't save the files correctly into your working directory.

Comment: related: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/11107541)